How to use DOUBLE as a verb
Context: There are 90 boys and 40 girls in a school.
Is it correct to say

The number of boys more than doubles that of girls.

Or

The number of boys is more than double that of girls.

How to use double/twice/two times to describe it in the most natural and accurate ways possible?

Your second sentence is correct. The number of X is double (or twice) that of Y, never 'two times', but for numbers higher than 2, use 'three times', 'four times', etc.

"double" can be used as a verb, but that's not how you're using it here. You can say "We doubled the number of cookies we could bake when we got a bigger oven."

Your second sentence works. There are many ways to say this, including:

The number of boys is more than twice that of girls.


There are more than twice as many boys as (there are) girls. (This is what I'd default to, personally.)


Boys outnumber girls by a factor of two.

The verb "double" means to make double or become double, never to be double, so your first sentence doesn't work.

You ask how to use the word double as a verb. Double can be transitive

He doubled his capital over two years.

It can also be used intransitively:

The membership of the club doubled once the new swimming pool was opened.

In both cases, something (his capital, the membership) increases by a factor of two. You can't use a verb to compare two things where one is twice as big as the other, because nothing is increasing by a factor of two.

+1 for including examples.

Your second example is grammatically correct and idiomatic; however, it is not using 'double' as a verb as you ask in your question title. In that second example, 'double' is an adjective modifying the pronoun "that" (which refers back to the previously-mentioned "number").
Your first example makes no sense because you're trying to use 'double' as a verb yet no action has taken place. As a verb, to double means to cause something to double in size, value etc. For example, if you blew air into a balloon, you might cause it to double in size from its original size. But in the context of your example, nothing has happened - no action has taken place. There is a number of boys, and a number of girls. Nothing has "doubled". You are simply comparing the number of one set to the other, so there is no place to use this word as a verb.
